# Is there a raycasting library in C++ that is simple and open source?

Tags: c++, terrain, raycasting

I'm looking for a library that will let me cast a ray into a scene model (it happens to be a terrain model in our case) and return the point of intersection in the scene.  It does not have to be super-efficient (although I'd rather it not be super-inefficient).  Ideally it would not have dependencies on other libraries (like OpenGL).  I'm really looking for something that has just the functionality I need and no  more.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: "simple" and "ray casting" are two things that probably together cannot coexist! You just need something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085096/simple-c-c-library-for-triangle-intersection-acceleration-structure

Comment: @Salvatore Preveti why not? Raycasting is simple, it ain't rocket science.

Comment: If you want to obtain decent performances you need a kd-tree, at least.

Comment: @WTP "So simple" that entire upperclassmen college courses are devoted to it... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there are other requirements you haven't revealed, use [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/)'s [AABB tree](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/AABB_tree/Chapter_main.html)'s support for ray intersections ([example](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/AABB_tree/Chapter_main.html#Subsection_63.3.2)).

(Please, don't even think about using this if you're actually trying to do terrain rendering though... there are far more efficient algorithms for ray-casting height fields for the purpose of producing images e.g so-called [voxel algorithms](http://www.codermind.com/articles/Voxel-terrain-engine-building-the-terrain.html)).

Comment: I looked at CGAL and I really like it.  Looks like it has a very straight-forward, well-documented interface.  Unfortunately, to do with it what we want I think we'd have to buy a commercial license.  I found that IPP, which we already use and have licenses for, has some ray casting functionality.  It doesn't appear to be as easy to use as CGAL, but since we're already using IPP in our project, I figure it is worth a try with that.